# How to setup Recaptcha on pages cached by Varnish?

Tags: 7, caching, proxies, captcha

On a site where a contact form is displayed at the bottom of each page, I implemented **Varnish** caching. To do so I had to deactivate Recaptcha to avoid 'no cache -must revalidate " headers.

I tried other antispam solutions such as **Honeypot** or **Botcha**, but Honeypot is not efficient (at least with time limit  disabled), and Botcha also invalidates cache. I'd really prefer to go on with Recaptcha

I tried also [Boost Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost_captcha) dev version : as per this [related Varnish issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2147871), it should be quite straightforward to make it work for Varnish. But this doesn't help, cache  is still invalidated.

Did anybody could make Recaptcha work with Varnish ?

Answer (score 1):

CAPTCHA and reCAPTCHA modules are incompatible with page caching.